# NWJS(Node-Webkit): How to get the default printer?

Tags: printing, default, node-webkit, printers, nwjs

I'm using NWJS (node-webkit) for an app where I need to print. From the [docs](https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#wingetprinterscallback) I see we can get a list of available printers with `win.getPrinters(callback)` however there is no way to know which one has been set as the default printer (by the OS?). I feel its possible because other softwares are able to detect and automatically select the default printer which is exactly what i'm trying to do. I didn't see any other function that could help in this.
So how do we do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a node module. Example:

`npm install --save systeminformation`

```js
const si = require('systeminformation');

si.printer()
  .then((printers) => {
    if (printers.length) {
      const defaultPrinter = printers.find((printer) => {
        return printer.default;
      });
      console.log({ printers, defaultPrinter });
    } else {
      console.log('No printers on this machine.');
    }
  });
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error checking printers', error);
  });
```

- [SystemInformation Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation#11-printer)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it's a good alternative (and maybe the only one) seems like NWJS printing API is very basic and doesn't allow what i want at all. Your pseudo sounds familiar to me, i think we talked on github or something..;